# Gray background printing on transparent images. Shows only when printing from Mac, but not PC

Tags: print-design, transparency

Transparent images are assumed to be originating from a PC/Window environment, and then have a light gray background when printed in color on a mac.

I am mocking up how it looks "printed".  It is fine when I flatten the image, however.

Is there any workaround for printing these transparent images on a mac without issues?

[image: Mockup]

Comment: This is caused by either improper gamma correction or profile mismatch. I expect the transparent item is composited on white *and then* color-matched for output which is pretty common. I think that "on a mac" is a little too general however: this is going to be software related. This sort of thing occurs via print driver over-enthusiasm and also e.g. PDF flattening. Can you give some idea of workflow?

Comment: Basically, this is from our HR having this issue - not myself.  They are printing from what I assume to be the latest OS, but the files likely originated from a Windows environment.  I am told that this is happening in multiple applications/file types.  Applications being Preview, Acrobat Reader, Word  and file types such as PDF's and Word docs

Comment: OK, my first thought is to try examining the printer's driver properties page at print time and see if disabling "color enhancement" "vivid photo" "silently alter your line art using a profile that only works for for puppies" helps. Generally, Windows uses 2.2 gamma, mac uses 1.8. Also, the printer gamma may be keyed off the monitor gamma which may be misconfigured on a per-system basis.

Comment: Extreme example: http://superuser.com/questions/579216/why-does-this-png-image-display-differently-in-chrome-firefox-than-in-safari-a